# Django - Displaying content based on permissions in a class based view

Tags: django, django-views

I want to display an edit link on certain content if the user has permission to edit the content. I've done some research and it appears that the best way to do this is via the view. I saw some vague suggestion to use permissions to add the link via context.

As a beginner, I am not sure how to go about this. Any suggestions?

The view:

```
class CompanyProjectsDetailView(UpdateView):
    queryset = Project.objects.get_with_counted_notes_documents_todos()
    template_name = 'company_accounts/project_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'project'
    form_class = ProjectStatusForm
```

The model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    description = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PROJECT_CHOICES, default="active")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, editable=False, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

    objects = ProjectManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('company_project:project_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: See this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#:~:text=The%20Django%20admin%20site%20uses,for%20that%20type%20of%20object.

Comment: How would you determine if the user has the permission to edit?

Comment: Bernhard it will be based on group permissions.